Level shifter (floating shifting ?)
I'm currently studying level shifters, and I have a question: Is it possible to design a level shifter that translates 0 and 5 volts to VSS (e.g., VSS = 5V) and VDD (e.g., VDD = 8V)? If so, could you explain how this could be done and how your solution works?
I already understand how level shifters work for up and down conversion with a ground reference, but everything I've found online is based on this ground reference. I think my question might involve floating supplies, but my knowledge in this area is limited, so I'm seeking your expertise.
If you have any helpful documents or resources, I would greatly appreciate it.

Sounds like you want an optocoupler. If so, it becomes an isolator rather than a level shifter.

The TLV1872 can do ground shifting without isolation, so it is certainly possible.

The level shift by itself would be pretty easy with a long tailed pair. It would probably be useful to operate it as a Schmitt trigger, too, as this has several advantages, including transition speed. But it won't drive much. So the outputs would be high impedance, so to speak. What are your requirements for the circuit that must be driven? (And this should include how precisely you require your 5V and 8V output levels, as well as the load presented by whatever it is you expect to drive and how fast you expect all this to be, as well.)

This comes up frequently in the work I do. I usually use SPDT analog switch chips. Just switch the output between Vss and Vdd depending in the logic input. The DG403 has been my go-to chip here for many years: flexible, wide voltage range, well behaved, but maybe a bit slow for some purposes.

I considered it, but SPDTs often introduce glitches at the rising and falling edges of the pulses. So I was looking for solutions based on transistors.
